# How to open specific email website using as link on my website?

Tags: html, email, gmail, href

User will register using his email. Probably he will use gmail or outlook.
How to make link that opens gmail.com when user registered with gmail account, or outlook account?
Is there some universal solution?
I am trying to avoid something like this:

```
if (user.email.endsWith("@gmail.com"))
   link.href="https://gmail.com"
else if...
else if...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell how a user reads their email. They might use a webmail service. They might use a desktop application. Even if they use GMail, they might not use the GMail website.

Presumably, you want to give the user a link so they can see the confirmation email to prove they can access email at the address they gave you.

There's no reliable way to help them do that (the approach you are trying to avoid is the most likely to work (for a *small* value of "most")).

Just **trust that the user knows how to read their own email** instead.

Comment: Just trust that the user knows how to read their own email. I trust but my UX designer doesn't :)

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what it is that you need to actually use it for, but if you need to open the link so that the user can send an email to an email address, you could always just use `mailto:`

```html
<div> Click to send an email to <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a></div>
```

This will will open the user's default mail service.